# Generate Skolem sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

### Skolem sequences

A *Skolem sequence* is a sequence of `2n` numbers where every number `i` between `1` and `n` occurs exactly twice, and the distance between the two occurrences of `i` is exactly `i` steps.
Here are some examples of Skolem sequences:

```
1 1
1 1 4 2 3 2 4 3
16 13 15 12 14 4 7 3 11 4 3 9 10 7 13 12 16 15 14 11 9 8 10 2 6 2 5 1 1 8 6 5
```

The following sequences are *not* Skolem sequences:

```
1 2 1 2      (The distance between the 1's is 2, not 1)
3 1 1 3      (The number 2 is missing)
1 1 2 1 1 2  (There are four 1's)
```

### Objective

Write a program, function, or expression to count the number of all Skolem sequences of a given length.
More explicitly, your input is an integer `n`, and your output is the number of Skolem sequences of length `2n`.
This sequence has an [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A004075).
For `n = 0`, you may return either `0` or `1`.
The first few values, starting from `0`, are

```
0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0, 0, 504, 2656, 0, 0, 455936, 3040560, 0, 0, 1400156768
```

### Rules and scoring

This is code golf.
Output format is lax within reason.

Comment: Just curious, but what is the `0, 1, 0, 0, 6...` in your question? Is that the code snippet, if so what language is that?

Comment: @PhiNotPi: It represents the number of Skolem sequences of length `2n`, starting at `n=0` (first element is 0).

Comment: "expression to count Skolem sequences of length n" -- I believe you meant "... of length 2n".

Comment: Why is the first item in your output `0`? If you're going to admit `0` as a valid input then the output should be `1`.

Comment: Some (including my code) believe that there are zero empty sequences.  If 1 makes you feel better, return it.

Comment: AFAIK in *every context* you assume there is one and only one empty sequence/null object/empty set etc/function-to/from-the-empty-set/empty graph/whatever else.

Comment: @boothby: Out of curiosity, what language is your program written in?

Comment: @Bakuriu Only fools argue about values of 0^0.

Comment: @boothby, did you just call Knuth a fool?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, probably.  Only fools go around saying things like "Only fools ___".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>48</strike> 46 characters

```
:b,1,{)2\?){{.2$&!{.2$|@@}*.+.4b?<}do;;}+%}@/,
```

The faster version ([try online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=NQoKOmIsMSx7KTJcPyl7ey4yJCYhey4yJHxAQH0qLisuNGI%2FPH1kbzs7fSslfUAvLA%3D%3D&run=true)) - runs reasonable fast, e.g. `n=8` takes about two seconds. And the chosen approach takes really few characters.

This version also works with bitmasks. It builts the possible result array from 1 upwards, i.e. for `n=3`:

```
1: 000011        000110 001100 011000 110000
2: 010111 101011 101110        011101 110101 111010
```

While some results (like 000011) have two possible continuations, others (i.e. 001100) have none and are removed from the result array.

Explanation of the code:

```
:b           # save the input into variable b for later use
,            # make the list 0..b-1 (the outer loop)
1,           # puts the list [0] on top of the stack - initially the only possible
             # combination
{)           # {...}@/ does the outer loop counting from i=1 to b
  2\?)       # computes the smalles possible bit mask m=2^i+1 with two bits set 
             # and distance of those equal to i (i.e. i=1: 11, i=2: 101, ...)
  {          # the next loop starts with this bitmask (prepended to code via
             # concatination {...}+
             # the loop itself iterates the top of the stack, i.e. at this point 
             # the result array                 
             # stack here contains item of result array (e.g. 00000011)
             # and bitmask (e.g. 00000101)
    {        # the inner-most loop tries all masks with the current item in the result set
      .2$&!  # do item and result set share not single bit? then - {...}*
      {
        .2$| # then generate the new entry by or-ing those two
        @@   # push it down on the stack (i.e. put working items to top)
      }*
      .+     # shift the bit mask left by one
      .4b?<  # if still in the range loop further
    }do;;    # removes the remainders of the loop (i.e. item processed and mask)
  }+%        # stack now contains the new result array
}@/
,            # length of result array, i.e. the number of Skolem sequences
```

Comment: Accepting the faster of tied solutions.

Answer (score 6):

### GolfScript (46 chars)

```
:&1,\,{0,2@)?)2&*{2${1$^}%@+\2*}*;+}/{4&?(=},,
```

This is an expression which takes input on the stack. To turn it into a full program which takes input on stdin, prepend `~`

It is fairly inefficient - most of the savings I made in golfing it down from 56 chars ungolfed were by expanding the range of loops in ways which don't introduce incorrect results but do waste calculation.

The approach is bitwise masking of Cartesian products. E.g. (using binary for the masks) for `n=4` the ungolfed code would compute the xor of each element in the Cartesian product `[00000011 00000110 ... 11000000] x [00000101 00001010 ... 10100000] x ... x [00010001 ... 10001000]`. Any result with 8 bits could only be achieved by non-overlapping masks.

In order to optimise for size rather than speed, the code accumulates partial products (`S1 u S1xS2 u S1xS2xS3 ...`) and makes each product be of `2n` elements rather than just the `2n-1-i` which can actually contribute to a valid sequence.

#### Speed

The golfed version runs for `n=5` in 10 seconds on my computer, and more than 5 minutes for `n=6`. The original ungolfed version computes `n=5` in less than a second, and `n=6` in about 1 minute. With a simple filter on intermediate results, it can compute `n=8` in 30 seconds. I've golfed it to 66 chars (as a program - 65 chars as an expression) while keeping the loops as restricted as possible and filtering intermediate collisions:

```
~:&1,\,{0,\).2\?)2&*@-{.{[\].~^.@~+<{;}*}+3$%@+\2*}*;\;}/{4&?(=},,
```

Comment: Damn. Just when I've thought my 48char J solution was good enough to be posted.

Comment: Damn. Our 47-character tie didn't last very long. +1

Answer (score 6):

#### J expression, 47 characters

```
 +/*/"1((=&{:+.2-#@])#;.2)\"1~.(i.!+:y)A.,~>:i.y
```

Example:

```
    y=:5
    +/*/"1((=&{:+.2-#@])#;.2)\"1~.(i.!+:y)A.,~>:i.y
10
```

Takes about 30 seconds for `y=:5` on my machine.

the algorithm is as slow as can be:

- `~.(i.!+:y)A.,~>:i.y` generates every permutation of `1 2 .. y 1 2 .. y` and removes duplicate entries
- `((=&{:+.2-#@])#;.2)\"1` computes:

  - `(...)\"1` for every prefix of every row:

    - `#;.2` counts the the elements before each occurence of the last element
    - `#@]` counts the number of counts (i.e. the number of occurences of the last element)
    - `=&{:` determines the "equality" "of" "last element"s of the count list and of the original list.
    - `+.` is a logical OR. `=&{:+.2-#@]` reads "either the last elements [of the count list and the original list] are equal, or there is only one element [in the count list] rather than two".
- `*/"1` multiplies (logical AND) over the rows of the condition table, determining which permutations are Skolem sequences.
- `+/` sums the ones and zeroes together.

Answer (score 5):

#### GolfScript, 49 characters

```
~:/..+?:d(,{d+/base(;:w;/,{.w?)w>1$?=},,/=},,/1=+
```

Expects the number `n` on STDIN. This is code-golf - don't try the code with `n` greater than 5.

Comment: Ouch, no greater than 5?

Comment: @boothby It was the first, direct attempt. We often have to take the decision speed vs. size - and code-golf is about size. That's why I also added the fast version - which originally was much longer but now is even shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>20</s></sup> 19 bytes

```
₁ḣ
ṁo=¹⁰(moF-¥)uPṘ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9odXNr///igoHhuKMK4bmBbz3CueKBsChtb0YtwqUpdVDhuZgy////NA)

Can be shortened further.

returns 1 for 0.

-1 byte from Jo king.

### Explanation

```
ṁo=ḣ¹`(moF-¥)ḣ¹uPṘ2ḣ
                   ḣ range from 1..n
                 Ṙ2  replicate each element 2 times
               uP    unique permutations of the list
ṁo                   map each permutation to the following two functions
                     and sum the results
     `               flip: f x y = f y x
      (mo   )        map each number to the following:
      (    ¥)ḣ¹      index of each number in 1..n in the permutation
      (  F- )        folded by subtraction
  =ḣ¹                are the differences equal to 1..n?
```

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 70

This is a little shorter than my original.

```
sum(1for i in DLXCPP([(i-1,j,i+j)for i in[1..n]for j in[n..3*n-i-1]]))
```

How it works:

Given a 0/1 matrix, the **exact cover** problem for that matrix is to find a subset of the rows that sum (as integers) to the all-ones vector.  For example,

```
11001
10100
01001
00011
00010
```

has a solution

```
10100
01001
00010
```

My favorite approach to problems is to cast them to an exact cover problem.  Skolem sequences efficiently facilitate this.  I make an exact cover problem where solutions are in bijection with Skolem sequences of length `2n`.  For example, a row of the problem for `n=6` is

```
  a   |  b  
001000|001001000000 # S[b] = S[b+a+1] = a
```

where a 1 in position `a < n` means that symbol `a` is used.  The remaining positions correspond to actual locations in the sequence.  An exact cover corresponds to each symbol being used exactly once, and each location being filled exactly once.  By construction, any symbol `k` in a location is `k` spaces away from its partner.

In Sage, `DLXCPP` is a "dancing links" implementation -- it solves the exact cover problem in an exceptionally graceful manner.  It's one of my favorite algorithms ever, and being right at the surface in Sage makes combinatorial enumeration a joy.

Comment: Wow, dancing link. Use `len(list(...))` will save 4 chars.

Comment: @Ray My computer would simply die if I computed `len(list(...))` for n=16.  And it'd utterly kill the runtime.

Comment: That's right, because converting a generator into a list cost many memory.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ý¦©€DœʒU®εXQ0Úg<}®Q}Ùg
```

Results in \$0\$ for \$n=0\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX//8OdwqbCqeKCrETFk8qSVcKuzrVYUTDDmmc8fcKuUX3DmWf//zQ) or [verify the test cases in the range \$[0,4]\$](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9vc2FiaWX/NMaSTj8iIOKGkiAiP07/w53CpsKp4oKsRMWTypJVwq7OtVhRMMOaZzx9wq5RfcOZZ/8s/w). (Unfortunately times out for \$n\geq5\$.)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý                 # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input `n`]
 ¦                # Remove the leading 0
                  # (builtin `L` would become list [1,0] for n=0 unfortunately,
                  # resulting in an incorrect result of 3 at the end)
  ©               # Store this list in variable `®` (without popping)
   €D             # Duplicate each, resulting in a flattened list [1,1,2,2,3,3,...,n,n]
     œ            # Get all permutations of this list
      ʒ           # Filter it by:
       U          #  Pop and store the current permutation in variable `X`
        ®         #  Push the ranged list [1,n] from variable `®`
         ε        #  Map it to:
          X       #   Check for each value in list `X`
           Q      #   whether it's equal to the current map value
                  #   (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
            0Ú    #   Remove all leading and trailing 0s
              g   #   Pop and get the length of the list
               <  #   Decrease it by 1
         }®Q      #  After the map: check if it's equal to the [1,n] ranged list
      }Ù          # After the filter: uniquify the remaining permutations
        g         # And pop and push the length
                  # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```